# Books on Polynomial Regression

Tags: regression, references, polynomial

I have read some books on statistics, and it covers most of the regression algorithm, but does not cover up much on polynomial regression. Any suggestions on books covering up this topic, specifically on cubic polynomial regression?

Comment: Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies covers cubic splines extensively.

Comment: I doubt that there is any book on cubic polynomial regression. If it were, then it would be a short book and about half would, or should, explain why it was usually a bad idea. Alternatively, if as @Sycorax infers, you are after a book mentioning cubic splines, Hastie and Tibshirani's Generalized Additive Models remains a good introduction with broader relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially answered in comments:

I doubt that there is any book on cubic polynomial regression. If it were, then it would be a short book and about half would, or should, explain why it was usually a bad idea. Alternatively, if as @Sycorax infers, you are after a book mentioning cubic splines, Hastie and Tibshirani's Generalized Additive Models remains a good introduction with broader relevance. – Nick Cox

Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies covers cubic splines extensively. – Sycorax